# Infinite Monkey Theorem: Maximum Recursion Depth exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, runtime-error

I was trying to solve the Infinite Monkey Theorem which is part of a programming assignment that I came across online.

The problem statement is:

> The theorem states that a monkey hitting keys at random on a typewriter keyboard for an infinite amount of time will almost surely type a given text, such as the complete works of William Shakespeare. Well, suppose we replace a monkey with a Python function. How long do you think it would take for a Python function to generate just one sentence of Shakespeare? The sentence we’ll shoot for is: “methinks it is like a weasel”

I am trying to see a) whether it will be possible to generate the string b) After how many iterations was the string generated

I have set recursion limit as 10000 looking at a previous SO question, but I am still getting the run time error for Maximum recursion depth reached.

I am still finding my way around python. I hope to see suggestions on how I could do it in a better way without coming across recursion depth issue.

Here is my code so far:

```
import random
import sys
alphabet=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',' ']
quote="methinks  it is like a weasel"
msg='cont'
count=0

sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

def generate(msg):
    sentence=''
    while len(sentence)!=27:
        #random.choice() prints a random element from list 'alphabet'
        sentence=sentence+random.choice(alphabet)
    if msg=='cont':
        verify(sentence)

def verify(msg2):
    global count
    if msg2.find(quote)==-1:
        count+=1
        generate('cont')

    else:
        print 'sentence is ',msg2 ,'count is',count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate(msg)
```

Comment: Use a loop, not recursion.

Comment: I don't really see how writing a program like this would answer any of the two questions you posed. It certainly is possible to generate this sentence by concatenating random characters. It may take just a single run or an arbitrarily large number of tries depending on your luck. It sounds like a problem to tackle with statistical analysis rather than a computer program that actually executes the task. The details of your implementation and the implementation of random functions in Python may affect the actual outcome significantly. As for the error, maybe you should use an iterative approach.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I shall try to use some method other than recursion. I was thinking of doing this using recursion.

Comment: There is a version of this proposed by Dawkins that use evolution by random changing one char x times from the most fit (the one most similar to end result). With that approach you get there in very few iterations. By pure chance it's not likely you will ever match your string. See [this PCG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17294/golfing-a-weasel-program)

Answer (score 5):

This is a case where it's better to think before doing.  If we ignore capitalization and punctuation, your string is comprised of 28 characters, each of which can in principle be any of the 26 letters of the alphabet or a space.  The number of combinations is 27<sup>28</sup>, which happens to be 11972515182562019788602740026717047105681. If you could enumerate a billion guesses per second, 27<sup>28</sup> / 1E9 (tries/sec) / 3600 (sec/hr) / 24 (hrs/day) / 365.25 (days/yr) / 14E9 (yrs/current age of universe)
=> 27099008032844.297. The good news is that you might stumble on the answer at any point, so the expected amount of time is only half of 27 trillion times the current age of the universe.

Blowing out the stack is the least of your problems.

The reason it's called the infinite monkey theorem is that you can divide by the number of monkeys who can process this in parallel, and if that's infinity the solution time becomes the per monkey amount of time to generate a guess, 1 billionth of a second.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better not to call `verify()` from `generate()` (and vice-versa) in the likely event that the monkeys have not written Shakespeare.

Having two functions which repeatedly call one another without returning if what causes the recursion depth to be exceeded.

Instead of using recursion, you could simply check whether you've produced your sentence with an iterative approach. For example have a loop which takes a random sentence, then checks whether it matches your required sentence, and if so, outputs the number of tries it took (and if not loops back to the start).

Answer (score 0):

```
done = False
count = 1
while not done:
    msg = generate()
    if verify(msg):
        print 'success, count = ', count
        done = True
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following.  It runs on CPython 2.[67], CPython 3.[01234], pypy 2.4.0, pypy3 2.3.1 and jython 2.7b3.  It should take a very long time to run with --production, even on pypy or pypy3.

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.4/bin/python

'''Infinite monkeys randomly typing Shakespeare (or one monkey randomly typing Shakespeare very fast'''

# pylint: disable=superfluous-parens
# superfluous-parens: Parentheses are good for clarity and portability

import sys
import itertools


def generate(alphabet, desired_string, divisor):
    '''Generate matches'''
    desired_tuple = tuple(desired_string)
    num_possibilities = len(alphabet) ** len(desired_string)
    for candidateno, candidate_tuple in enumerate(itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=len(desired_string))):
        if candidateno % divisor == 0:
            sys.stderr.write('checking candidateno {0} ({1}%)\n'.format(candidateno, candidateno * 100.0 / num_possibilities))
        if candidate_tuple == desired_tuple:
            match = ''.join(candidate_tuple)
            yield match


def usage(retval):
    '''Output a usage message'''
    sys.stderr.write('Usage: {0} --production\n'.format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(retval)


def print_them(alphabet, quote, divisor):
    '''Print the matches'''
    for matchno, match in enumerate(generate(alphabet, quote, divisor)):
        print('{0} {1}'.format(matchno, match))


def main():
    '''Main function'''
    production = False

    while sys.argv[1:]:
        if sys.argv[1] == '--production':
            production = True
        elif sys.argv[1] in ['--help', '-h']:
            usage(0)
        else:
            sys.stderr.write('{0}: Unrecognized option: {1}\n'.format(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1]))
            usage(1)

    if production:
        print_them(alphabet='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ', quote='methinks it is like a weasel', divisor=10000)
    else:
        print_them(alphabet='abcdef', quote='cab', divisor=10)


main()
```